# How to update model in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have AJAX request in Angular JS that returns HTML content with `ng-model`:

```
request.success(function (data) {
   $scope.templateForm = data.html;                  
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div compile="templateForm"></div>
```

**Angular JS:**
My dirrective compile is:

```
.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(
                    function (scope) {
                        // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
                        return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
                    },
                    function (value) {
                        // when the 'compile' expression changes
                        // assign it into the current DOM
                        element.html(value);

                        // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
                        // scope.
                        // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
                        // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
                        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                    }
                );
            };
        }])
```

Problem is that `ng-model` in `$scope.templateForm` for next AJAX response in not work. How I can update ng-model if I get other HTML in response?

When I make first click on link to get content I get in response with HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-minlength="10" required>
```

When I make second click I get other content with HTML:

```
<textarea ng-model="description"></textarea>
```

Outside of this content there is static HTML with button:

```
<div ng-disabled="shareForm.$invalid">Do</div>
```

When I get first HTML with input, then block with `ng-disabled` does not work, so it must be disabled, because `input` is empty.

Comment: why are you trying to save angular templates as variables rather than using the normal template services?

Comment: Normal template service does not update `ng-model` for each loaded templare in response

Comment: I understand that, but why is your template a variable? templates are meant to be in html, and there are services like ng-include that allow you to dynamically inject them.  saving angular templates as variables generally does not work.

Comment: Can you give example please, I dont understand you

Comment: No, that's what I'm saying, what you are doing doesn't make sense.  you are trying to store markup as data, which isn't going to work as you intend without ALOT of custom work.

Comment: you can't have angular expressions (i.e. `{{somevariable}}`) inside another variable like this.  by the time the directive is rendered and the HTML content of the template is rendered, the digest cycle is already complete and the new expressions can't be bound to variables on `$scope`.

Comment: and if you *aren't* using expressions, then just assigning the template in the HTML using sce (`$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.templateForm)`) would render the HTML, without needing compile.

Comment: If use  `rustAsHtml` I get HTML as text on page

Comment: there are multiple questions from people who have tried to do this same thing (I'll have to search to find some of the posts) but the general consensus is that you really shouldn't be doing it this way.  dynamically generated angular will require you to write your own parser.

Comment: and I'm not sure that you even framed your question well, because it doesn't seem as though the answers provided are addressing the problem.  perhaps if you can edit the question and show what is being returned in data.html, it might help clarify the issue.

Comment: ok, so you are wanting to add an element with a validator to an existing form, and have the form be aware that a new element was added, and apply the validations to the new element along with the elements that were already in place?

Answer (score 0):

include the angular-sanitize.min.js resource, i.e.:

```
request.success(function (data) {
      $scope.templateForm = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.html);              
});
```

Html

```
<div ng-bind-html="templateForm "></div>
```

Comment: If it work for you please approve it as answer for your question. Thanks

Comment: I get error:` Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
    at Error (native)`

Comment: did you try this simply??
request.success(function (data) {
      $scope.templateForm = data.html;
});

Comment: I get HTML from ajax in variable `$scope.templateForm` after in HTML template I have `{{templateForm}}`

Comment: It works but does not work `required` and `ng-disabled` in textarea at `$scope.templateForm`